# What's the difference in force between lifting an object out of a viscous fluid (like honey) versus air?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, estimation, drag, viscosity

Roughly, how much more force does it take to lift a stick out of a viscous fluid (like honey) than the same object the same distance in air?

I'm not looking for a hard number- more like a back of the envelope, order of magnitude answer.

Looking into it online as a non-physicist it seems like the greatest difference is drag- pulling up on the stick in a viscous liquid causes so much more drag than in air.

I found the Stokes equation for viscous liquids which seems like a good way to estimate the drag (F=6pi * viscosity * radius * velocity).

Going very very roughly, with the viscosity of honey ranging from 2 to 10 pascal seconds, it seems like lifting a stick out of the honey should take 2-10x more force (assuming lifting velocity is held constant), which kind of seems right?

But if we look at more viscous liquids like peanut butter, with a viscosity of around 1000 pascal seconds at the high end, it seems ludicrous- it's a thousand times harder to lift out of peanut butter? That doesn't seem right. But maybe stating velocity is the same in these situations is where it breaks down.

Anyway, if there is a better way to frame this question or any clarifications it would be much appreciated! I haven't studied physics since intro level in college years ago.

Comment: Pushing a stick *through* peanut butter may be that much harder. Pulling something out has more to do with the stickiness of the material than the viscosity

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to quantify/measure stickiness?

Comment: seems like a sticky topic to cover..... https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31619/how-is-the-stickiness-of-a-fluid-measured

Comment: thanks so much :)

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track.  But that factor of 2 to 10 for honey seems very low.  What did you used for the viscosity of air?

Comment: Air is around 10^-5 pascal seconds- i was just discounting drag from air because it seems like it would be low